# Referring to an email sent to an individual, but not in the main conversation

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, phrase-requests, email

Consider this situation :
Somebody (A) sends a mail with subject S, to many folks (B,C,D) who send few responses to all recipients, with the same subject S, meaning that these mails are all part of the mail chain.

Now, B sends a reply, to C only, with few concerns.

After that, few more mails are sent to all in the main conversation.

Finally, B wants to send the same concerns to wider audience (send to all) and starts typing the same matter which he had sent to C earlier.

B wants to point out that he had already communicated this to C. **How does he refer to that earlier mail ?**

Basically I want to fill in X in this sentence:
"I want to raise the following concerns, which I had sent to C earlier in a/an **X** mail"

I tried the following templates for X :
a **personal** mail : but mail was not personal
a **confidential** mail : but mail was not confidential
a **secret** mail : but mail was not secret
an **offline** mail : but mail was not sent offline
a **separate** mail : sounds ok
a **side conversation** mail : sounds ok
an **aside** mail : sounds ok , but "aside" may be taken to mean "unrelated"
a **fork** mail : sounds ok & weird at the same time

Right now, I am going with **separate** or **side conversation** , but wondering if others can suggest a more suitable word or phrase.
I can rephrase the sentence to avoid my problem, but I would like to see what words are more commonly used.

Comment: If 3 people have found this question acceptable and have given 3 answers , I wonder why somebody has downvoted this question. A comment on how to improve my question will be very useful. I have done my best to explain the situation , and gave my choice of words and asked specifically for what other words are more suitable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try ***sidebar***, defined as "a discussion between the lawyers and the judge held out of earshot of the jury" (sense 1.3, [here](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/sidebar)).

It can be used more generally to mean any small conversation between some members of a group outside earshot of the rest of the members.

> I want to raise the following concerns, which I had sent to C earlier in a ***sidebar***.

It seems to me to be slightly better than *aside*, because the connotations of insignificance are weaker.

Comment: +1 , Nice , "sidebar" is more common than "aside". I think , "in a sidebar **mail**" is also okay ?

Comment: @Prem, I do *not* think "sidebar mail" is okay. "Sidebar" should only be used as a noun, *not* as an adjective.

Answer (score 1):

"I want to raise the following concerns, which I had sent to C in an earlier mail **addressed to a restricted/limited audience**."

Answer (score 0):

Definitions of
[simultaneous
1
adj occurring or operating at the same time
Synonyms:
co-occurrent, coincident, coincidental, coinciding, concurrent, cooccurring
synchronal, synchronic, synchronous
occurring or existing at the same time or having the same period or phase]

### https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/simultaneous

***I would press the world "simultaneous" into service here because both C and others were being contacted around same time and on the same subject.***

Comment: Not sure if this works. I want to highlight that I sent it to C only , not that I sent simultaneous mails.